# Using find_all in BeautifulSoup when the filter is based on two distinct elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Currently I do it this way to pass only when there is a `tf-match-analyst-verdict` element inside the `div` which in turn should contain a `class` called `match-header`:

```python
matches = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "match-header"})
for match in matches:
    if (match.find('tf-match-analyst-verdict')):
```

which method is correct to pass this need in the creation of the `matches` object to remove the need to use `if`?

Comment: If BS4's selector syntax supports `:has()`, you can use `soup.select('div.match-header:has(tf-match-analyst-verdict)')`

Comment: Hi @Barmar It perfectly solved my need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `select()` instead of `find_all()`. Then you can use the `:has()` selector.

```
matches = soup.select('div.match-header:has(tf-match-analyst-verdict)')
```

`:has(selector)` means that the element contains a descendant that matches the selector.